# Displaying Controls Based on Selected / Active Object Not Working as Expected

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm having an issue where if I add an image from my computer, click it, and then click IText the applicable controls aren't displayed. If I just click on the IText, it works. If I add an image, click it, click off of the image, then click the IText, it works; but not when I select an image and then the IText.

How would I go about displaying the applicable controls consistently (text + delete when IText is selected, and the delete only when an image is selected; as it doesn't need text controls)?

```js
// Add image from local
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

// display/hide controls
canvas.on('object:selected', function(e) {
   document.getElementById('trash').hidden = false;
   document.getElementById('forward').hidden = false;
   document.getElementById('back').hidden = false;
   if (e.target.type === 'i-text') {
      document.getElementById('textControls').hidden = false;
   }
});
canvas.on('before:selection:cleared', function(e) {
   document.getElementById('trash').hidden = true;
   document.getElementById('forward').hidden = true;
   document.getElementById('back').hidden = true;
   if (e.target.type === 'i-text') {
      document.getElementById('textControls').hidden = true;
   }
});

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function(e) {
   var file = e.target.files[0];
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function(f) {
      var data = f.target.result;
      fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function(img) {
         var oImg = img.set({
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            angle: 00,
            stroke: '#F0F0F0', //<-- set this
            strokeWidth: 40 //<-- set this
         }).scale(0.2);
         canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
         //var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
         var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
            format: 'png',
            quality: 1
         });
      });
   };
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
// Delete selected object
window.deleteObject = function() {
   canvas.getActiveObject().remove();
}
// Refresh page
function refresh() {
   setTimeout(function() {
      location.reload()
   }, 100);
}
// Add text
function Addtext() {
   canvas.add(new fabric.IText('Tap and Type', {
      left: 50,
      top: 100,
      fontFamily: 'helvetica neue',
      fill: '#333',
      stroke: '#F0F0F0',
      strokeWidth: 1,
      fontSize: 45
   }));
}
document.getElementById('text-color').onchange = function() {
   canvas.getActiveObject().setFill(this.value);
   canvas.renderAll();
};
document.getElementById('text-color').onchange = function() {
   canvas.getActiveObject().setFill(this.value);
   canvas.renderAll();
};
document.getElementById('text-bg-color').onchange = function() {
   canvas.getActiveObject().setBackgroundColor(this.value);
   canvas.renderAll();
};
document.getElementById('text-lines-bg-color').onchange = function() {
   canvas.getActiveObject().setTextBackgroundColor(this.value);
   canvas.renderAll();
};
document.getElementById('text-stroke-color').onchange = function() {
   canvas.getActiveObject().setStroke(this.value);
   canvas.renderAll();
};
document.getElementById('text-stroke-width').onchange = function() {
   canvas.getActiveObject().setStrokeWidth(this.value);
   canvas.renderAll();
};
document.getElementById('font-family').onchange = function() {
   canvas.getActiveObject().setFontFamily(this.value);
   canvas.renderAll();
};
document.getElementById('text-font-size').onchange = function() {
   canvas.getActiveObject().setFontSize(this.value);
   canvas.renderAll();
};
document.getElementById('text-line-height').onchange = function() {
   canvas.getActiveObject().setLineHeight(this.value);
   canvas.renderAll();
};
document.getElementById('text-align').onchange = function() {
   canvas.getActiveObject().setTextAlign(this.value);
   canvas.renderAll();
};
radios5 = document.getElementsByName("fonttype"); // wijzig naar button
for (var i = 0, max = radios5.length; i < max; i++) {
   radios5[i].onclick = function() {
      if (document.getElementById(this.id).checked == true) {
         if (this.id == "text-cmd-bold") {
            canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontWeight", "bold");
         }
         if (this.id == "text-cmd-italic") {
            canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontStyle", "italic");
         }
         if (this.id == "text-cmd-underline") {
            canvas.getActiveObject().set("textDecoration", "underline");
         }
         if (this.id == "text-cmd-linethrough") {
            canvas.getActiveObject().set("textDecoration", "line-through");
         }
         if (this.id == "text-cmd-overline") {
            canvas.getActiveObject().set("textDecoration", "overline");
         }
      } else {
         if (this.id == "text-cmd-bold") {
            canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontWeight", "");
         }
         if (this.id == "text-cmd-italic") {
            canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontStyle", "");
         }
         if (this.id == "text-cmd-underline") {
            canvas.getActiveObject().set("textDecoration", "");
         }
         if (this.id == "text-cmd-linethrough") {
            canvas.getActiveObject().set("textDecoration", "");
         }
         if (this.id == "text-cmd-overline") {
            canvas.getActiveObject().set("textDecoration", "");
         }
      }
      canvas.renderAll();
   }
}
// Send selected object to front or back
var selectedObject;
canvas.on('object:selected', function(event) {
   selectedObject = event.target;
});
var sendSelectedObjectBack = function() {
   canvas.sendToBack(selectedObject);
}
var sendSelectedObjectToFront = function() {
   canvas.bringToFront(selectedObject);
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue";
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.myFile {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
.myFile input[type="file"] {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.footerheader {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<a href="index.html">Testing</a>
<br>
<br>
<label class="myFile">
    <button>+ Photo</button>&nbsp;
    <input type="file" id="file" />
</label>
<button onclick="Addtext()">+ Text</button> / Selected Object:
<button id="trash" onClick="deleteObject()" hidden>Trash</button>
<button id="forward" onclick="sendSelectedObjectToFront()" hidden>Forward</button>
<button id="back" onclick="sendSelectedObjectBack()" hidden>Back</button> /
<button onclick="refresh()">Clear All</button>
<canvas id="c" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

<div id="textControls" hidden>
    <h2>Test Text Controls</h2>
    <div id="text-wrapper" style="margin-top: 10px" ng-show="getText()">
        <div id="text-controls">
            <input type="color" id="text-color" size="10">
            <label for="font-family" style="display:inline-block">Font family:</label>
            <select id="font-family">
                <option value="arial">Arial</option>
                <option value="helvetica" selected>Helvetica</option>
                <option value="myriad pro">Myriad Pro</option>
                <option value="delicious">Delicious</option>
                <option value="verdana">Verdana</option>
                <option value="georgia">Georgia</option>
                <option value="courier">Courier</option>
                <option value="comic sans ms">Comic Sans MS</option>
                <option value="impact">Impact</option>
                <option value="monaco">Monaco</option>
                <option value="optima">Optima</option>
                <option value="hoefler text">Hoefler Text</option>
                <option value="plaster">Plaster</option>
                <option value="engagement">Engagement</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <label for="text-align" style="display:inline-block">Text align:</label>
            <select id="text-align">
                <option value="left">Left</option>
                <option value="center">Center</option>
                <option value="right">Right</option>
                <option value="justify">Justify</option>
            </select>
            <div>
                <label for="text-bg-color">Background color:</label>
                <input type="color" id="text-bg-color" size="10">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="text-lines-bg-color">Background text color:</label>
                <input type="color" id="text-lines-bg-color" size="10">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="text-stroke-color">Stroke color:</label>
                <input type="color" id="text-stroke-color">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="text-stroke-width">Stroke width:</label>
                <input type="range" value="1" min="1" max="5" id="text-stroke-width">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="text-font-size">Font size:</label>
                <input type="range" min="1" max="120" step="1" id="text-font-size">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="text-line-height">Line height:</label>
                <input type="range" min="0" max="10" step="0.1" id="text-line-height">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="text-controls-additional">
            <input type='checkbox' name='fonttype' id="text-cmd-bold"> Bold
            <input type='checkbox' name='fonttype' id="text-cmd-italic"> Italic
            <input type='checkbox' name='fonttype' id="text-cmd-underline"> Underline
            <input type='checkbox' name='fonttype' id="text-cmd-linethrough"> Linethrough
            <input type='checkbox' name='fonttype' id="text-cmd-overline"> Overline
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="footerheader">asdasd</div>

            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>1</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using version >2.x.x, then to get selected object use events

```
canvas.on('selection:created', onObjectSelected);
canvas.on('selection:updated', onObjectSelected);
```

And named setter/ getter is optional in build,so don't use.

***DEMO***

```js
// Add image from local
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var selectedObject;
// display/hide controls
canvas.on('selection:created', onObjectSelected);
canvas.on('selection:updated', onObjectSelected);

function onObjectSelected(e) {
   selectedObject = e.selected[0];
   document.getElementById('trash').hidden = false;
   document.getElementById('forward').hidden = false;
   document.getElementById('back').hidden = false;
   if (selectedObject.type === 'i-text') {
      document.getElementById('textControls').hidden = false;
   }else
    document.getElementById('textControls').hidden = true;
};
canvas.on('selection:cleared', function(e) {
   selectedObject = null;
   document.getElementById('trash').hidden = true;
   document.getElementById('forward').hidden = true;
   document.getElementById('back').hidden = true;
   document.getElementById('textControls').hidden = true;
});

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function(e) {
   var file = e.target.files[0];
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function(f) {
      var data = f.target.result;
      fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function(img) {
         var oImg = img.set({
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            angle: 00,
            stroke: '#F0F0F0', //<-- set this
            strokeWidth: 40 //<-- set this
         }).scale(0.2);
         canvas.add(oImg);
      });
   };
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
// Delete selected object
window.deleteObject = function() {
   canvas.remove(canvas.getActiveObject());
}
// Refresh page
function refresh() {
   setTimeout(function() {
      canvas.clear()
   }, 100);
}
// Add text
function Addtext() {
   canvas.add(new fabric.IText('Tap and Type', {
      left: 50,
      top: 100,
      fontFamily: 'helvetica neue',
      fill: '#333',
      stroke: '#F0F0F0',
      strokeWidth: 1,
      fontSize: 45
   }));
}
document.getElementById('text-color').onchange = function() {
   selectedObject.fill = this.value;
   selectedObject.dirty = true;
   canvas.renderAll();
};
document.getElementById('text-bg-color').onchange = function() {
   selectedObject.backgroundColor = this.value;
   selectedObject.dirty = true;
   canvas.renderAll();
};
document.getElementById('text-lines-bg-color').onchange = function() {
   selectedObject.textBackgroundColor = this.value;
   selectedObject.dirty = true;
   canvas.renderAll();
};
document.getElementById('text-stroke-color').onchange = function() {
   selectedObject.stroke = this.value;
   selectedObject.dirty = true;
   canvas.renderAll();
};
document.getElementById('text-stroke-width').onchange = function() {
   selectedObject.strokeWidth = this.value;
   selectedObject.dirty = true;
   canvas.renderAll();
};
document.getElementById('font-family').onchange = function() {
   selectedObject.fontFamily = this.value;
   selectedObject.dirty = true;
   canvas.renderAll();
};
document.getElementById('text-font-size').onchange = function() {
   selectedObject.fontSize = this.value;
   selectedObject.dirty = true;
   canvas.renderAll();
};
document.getElementById('text-line-height').onchange = function() {
   selectedObject.lineHeight = this.value;
   selectedObject.dirty = true;
   canvas.renderAll();
};
document.getElementById('text-align').onchange = function() {
   selectedObject.textAlign = this.value;
   selectedObject.dirty = true;
   canvas.renderAll();
};
radios5 = document.getElementsByName("fonttype"); // wijzig naar button
for (var i = 0, max = radios5.length; i < max; i++) {
   radios5[i].onclick = function() {
      if (document.getElementById(this.id).checked == true) {
         if (this.id == "text-cmd-bold") {
            selectedObject.fontWeight = "bold";
         }
         if (this.id == "text-cmd-italic") {
            selectedObject.fontStyle = "italic";
         }
         if (this.id == "text-cmd-underline") {
            selectedObject.underline = true;
         }
         if (this.id == "text-cmd-linethrough") {
            selectedObject.linethrough = true;
         }
         if (this.id == "text-cmd-overline") {
            selectedObject.overline = true;
         }
      } else {
         if (this.id == "text-cmd-bold") {
            selectedObject.fontWeight = "";
         }
         if (this.id == "text-cmd-italic") {
            selectedObject.fontStyle = "";
         }
         if (this.id == "text-cmd-underline") {
            selectedObject.underline = false;
         }
         if (this.id == "text-cmd-linethrough") {
            selectedObject.linethrough = false;
         }
         if (this.id == "text-cmd-overline") {
            selectedObject.overline = false;
         }
      }
      selectedObject.dirty = true;
      canvas.renderAll();
   }
}
// Send selected object to front or back

var sendSelectedObjectBack = function() {
   canvas.sendToBack(selectedObject);
}
var sendSelectedObjectToFront = function() {
   canvas.bringToFront(selectedObject);
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue";
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.myFile {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
.myFile input[type="file"] {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.footerheader {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<a href="index.html">Testing</a>
<br>
<br>
<label class="myFile">
    <button>+ Photo</button>&nbsp;
    <input type="file" id="file" />
</label>
<button onclick="Addtext()">+ Text</button> / Selected Object:
<button id="trash" onClick="deleteObject()" hidden>Trash</button>
<button id="forward" onclick="sendSelectedObjectToFront()" hidden>Forward</button>
<button id="back" onclick="sendSelectedObjectBack()" hidden>Back</button> /
<button onclick="refresh()">Clear All</button>
<canvas id="c" width=300 height=300></canvas>

<div id="textControls" hidden>
    <h2>Test Text Controls</h2>
    <div id="text-wrapper" style="margin-top: 10px" ng-show="getText()">
        <div id="text-controls">
            <input type="color" id="text-color" size="10">
            <label for="font-family" style="display:inline-block">Font family:</label>
            <select id="font-family">
                <option value="arial">Arial</option>
                <option value="helvetica" selected>Helvetica</option>
                <option value="myriad pro">Myriad Pro</option>
                <option value="delicious">Delicious</option>
                <option value="verdana">Verdana</option>
                <option value="georgia">Georgia</option>
                <option value="courier">Courier</option>
                <option value="comic sans ms">Comic Sans MS</option>
                <option value="impact">Impact</option>
                <option value="monaco">Monaco</option>
                <option value="optima">Optima</option>
                <option value="hoefler text">Hoefler Text</option>
                <option value="plaster">Plaster</option>
                <option value="engagement">Engagement</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <label for="text-align" style="display:inline-block">Text align:</label>
            <select id="text-align">
                <option value="left">Left</option>
                <option value="center">Center</option>
                <option value="right">Right</option>
                <option value="justify">Justify</option>
            </select>
            <div>
                <label for="text-bg-color">Background color:</label>
                <input type="color" id="text-bg-color" size="10">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="text-lines-bg-color">Background text color:</label>
                <input type="color" id="text-lines-bg-color" size="10">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="text-stroke-color">Stroke color:</label>
                <input type="color" id="text-stroke-color">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="text-stroke-width">Stroke width:</label>
                <input type="range" value="1" min="1" max="5" id="text-stroke-width">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="text-font-size">Font size:</label>
                <input type="range" min="1" max="120" step="1" id="text-font-size">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="text-line-height">Line height:</label>
                <input type="range" min="0" max="10" step="0.1" id="text-line-height">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="text-controls-additional">
            <input type='checkbox' name='fonttype' id="text-cmd-bold"> Bold
            <input type='checkbox' name='fonttype' id="text-cmd-italic"> Italic
            <input type='checkbox' name='fonttype' id="text-cmd-underline"> Underline
            <input type='checkbox' name='fonttype' id="text-cmd-linethrough"> Linethrough
            <input type='checkbox' name='fonttype' id="text-cmd-overline"> Overline
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="footerheader">asdasd</div>

            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>1</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is close, but if you 1) add text, 2) add an image from your computer, 3) select the text you added, 4) then select the image, the text controls remain (they should only be displayed if text is selected)

Comment: @codeforever are you creating group of text and image?

Comment: Hi, no, I mean selecting them separately

Comment: It seems to still be doing the same thing. If you select text the controls are displayed but if you then select the image that you add the controls for text should disappear but they don’t

Comment: that's it! Cheers.